# Django-lettuce: where to keep language file

Tags: python, django, bdd, lettuce

I've added lettuce into my django project, where to keep the `languages.py` file in django project instead of modifying lettuce itself?

Sultan

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of lettuce, but I am guessing that you can include your file `languages.py` anywhere python can find it.

I do this by appending the directory containing my files into `sys.path`. You could overwrite PYTHONPATH instead. A directory containing python code should have a `__init__.py` file.

I am not sure if you already tried the above. If you did, you can ignore my answer.

Comment: I was considering this way but I was wondering if lettuce somehow supports this feature for django